# How to resolve FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

**Code**:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
output_path = r'C:\\Users\\windows\\Documents\\test\\'

txt_files=glob.glob1(output_path,'Region_*.txt')

for txt_file in txt_files:
    print(txt_file) # here output is received as Region_CAN.txt
    df1 = pd.DataFrame()
    df1 = pd.read_csv(txt_file,sep='\t')
    print(df1)
```

output is received for `print(txt_file)`
however it cannot read the txt_file.

**Error**:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Region_CAN.txt'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glob.glob1(dirname, pattern)` method only returns the filenames. You need to provide the full path of txt file to `pd.read_csv()`.

You can do with `glob.glob(pathname)`

```py
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd


output_path = r'C:\\Users\\windows\\Documents\\test\\'

txt_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(output_path, 'Region_*.txt'))

for txt_file in txt_files:
    df1 = pd.read_csv(txt_file, sep='\t')
    print(df1)
```

Secondly, there is no need to initialize `df1` with `pd.DataFrame()` since `pd.read_csv` already returns the built dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

the file path need to join the directory

```py
for txt_file in txt_files:
    print(txt_file) # here output is received as Region_CAN.txt
    df1 = pd.DataFrame()
    file_name = os.path.join(output_path, txt_file)
    df1 = pd.read_csv(file_name,sep='\t')
    print(df1)
```

Answer (score 0):

For me in Jupyter lab I shut down and restarted the kernel as you suggested and it’s worked.